# Is it possible to take a picture with the top half of a camera feed, then the bottom half?

Tags: camera, raspicam, processor-speed, process

Is it possible to take a picture with the top half of a camera feed, then the bottom half? and would it require half as much processing power?

Comment: interesting question .... it would depend on the camera mostly .... what research have you done?

Comment: the 5 mega pixel one?

Comment: I'm not sure the "5 mega pixel one" narrows the hardware. What exact model, or which "camera feed"?

Comment: @Daverry, if you paint 1/2 of a room, and then wait a day, then paint the other 1/2 of the room, do you use 1/2 of the paint in total, or do only 1/2 of the work in total?

Comment: Thanks @jsotola, I was meaning if I take a picture with the top half does it only take half as much processing ie does the computer process the bottom half and just not show/save it? I'm using the raspberry pi zero with the 5 mp camera sold by raspberry pi

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It's raspberry pi hardware??